# How to create unit test for whole of projects (databases included)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have some projects using ASP.NET, I was created unit tests for some functions in my projects which is not involved with databases. But, I have not created unit tests for the other parts which is involved with databases.

I don't know what should I do for complete unit tests for whole of my projects.
And how to create unit tests for some functions that involving by databases?

Comment: Tests which "touching" database or other externals resources are not unit tests - it is integration tests. You create them in same way as unit tests but you need configure database connections and data required for the tests

Answer (score 0):

A unit test, as the name suggests, should be a true unit and should be independently testable. When a function depends on some external factors like a service or database call it is quite difficult to predict the outcome as several other factors come to play like network availability or latency etc.

To ensure that our method should be independent from external dependencies, it is advised that we must Mock them in our test application. This can be achieved through any compatible mocking framework, one such framework is the Moq Framework found at https://github.com/moq/moq4

Comment: A mocking framework is the only solution that can help you unit test external services / IO / database calls. Now its a different story whether you're able to comprehend these frameworks or not. So, unless you have some other thoughts, please mark this as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle this problem in ASP.NET is to create an interface like:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    void Delete(MyItemType item);
    void Update(MyItemType  item);
    void Insert(MyItemType item);
}
```

You then code your untested methods or their parent classes to accept the interface as a dependency parameter and then create a concrete wrapper class:

```
public class DatabaseImplementation : IDatabase
{
    //Implement interface here and wrap calls to real database
}
```

You will then need to inject this class, which can be done manually, but I would highly recommend reading about inversion of control and dependency injection. You can then use an inversion of control framework like Castle Windsor or StructureMap to take care of things automagically for you.

This now gives you full unit testing control, as you can use a mocking framework like moq to create a mock implementation of IDatabase, which will allow you to instruct the mock how to behave when Delete, Update, Insert etc. are called.

You can even use the inversion of control framework to automatically inject your mocks in your unit tests, if you find that helpful.

I know that sounds like a lot of reading and work, but these concepts make unit testing beautiful and also encourage you to design your code in a maintainable manner.

Good luck!